# Solution review

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> The variables $p,q,r$ and $s$ are correlated with each other with the following
>
> relationships $\dfrac{s^{0.5}}{p}=\dfrac{q}{r^2}$ .The ranges of values of
>
> $p,q$ and $r$ are respectively: $-0.04\leq p\leq -0.03,-0.25\leq q\leq-0.09,1\leq r\leq 7$.
>
> Determine the difference between the maximum and minimum value of $s$?

$a.)\ -0.02\\
b.)\ 0.02\\
c.)\ 0.1  \\
d.)\ \text{none of these}$

I concluded that the answer is $d.)$ but the book is saying something else.
So I am not sure if I am missing something.

**Solution by book**

> > The equation can be rewritten as $s^{0.5}=\dfrac{pq}{r^2}$.
> >
> > The maximum of $s^{2}$ will happen when we take exterme
> >
> > values of $p,q$ and $r$ in order to support the maximization of $s^{2}$
> >
> > Taking $p=-0.4,\ q=-0.25$
> >
> > and $r=1$ we get $s^2=\dfrac{-0.04\times -0.25}{1}\rightarrow s^{0.5}=1$
> >
> > Maximum value of $s=0.01$
> >
> > Minimum value of $s=-0.01$
> >
> > So, required difference $=0.02$

Comment: I think you have a typo in the part of "solution by book". (for example, $-0.4$ and $s^2$)

Comment: $-0.4$ seems ok , but $s^2$ looks typo for me. The solution is same in book as i showed here.

Comment: The whole thing looks like a massive typo throughout, for example $-0.04 \cdot -0.25 = 0.01 \neq 1$

Comment: The book's solution gives headache.

Answer (score 2):

Since we have $\sqrt{s} = \frac{pq}{r^2}$ then the maximum value of $s$ will be given by maximising $p^2q^2$ and minimising $r^4$.

Then, maximising $p^2q^2$ and minimising $r^4$ yields $$\max s = 0.04^2 \cdot 0.25^2 = 0.0001$$

To minimise $s$, we need to maximise $r^4$ by taking $r=7$ and minimise $p^2q^2$ so that we get $$\min s = \frac{0.03^2 \cdot 0.09^2}{7^4}.$$

Hence the difference is given by $$\max s - \min s = 0.0001 - \frac{0.00000729}{2401}$$